# Why does my code run correctly in JGRASP but in mindtap im getting "Getting Exception in thread "main"

Tags: java

So Im taking an intro to Java class through Cengage MindTap and the goal for the assignment was to continuously prompt a user for a password until they enter at least 2 uppercase three lowercase and one number. My code works in JGrasp but when I go to run the checks on mindtap, it seems the program is failing on the second loop after an incorrect password was entered. Below is my code that works on JGrasp and the error I get is:

`Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found`
    `at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)`
    `at ValidatePassword.main(ValidatePassword.java:13)`

```
import java.util.*;
public class ValidatePassword {
public static void main(String[] args) {
boolean valid = false;
while (valid == false)
{ 
String password;
int lowerCase = 0;
int upperCase = 0;
int numbers = 0;
System.out.println("Enter a password: ");
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
password = keyboard.nextLine();

for(int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++)
{
char c = password.charAt(i);
if (Character.isUpperCase(c))
{
upperCase++;
}
if (Character.isLowerCase(c))
{
lowerCase++;
}
if (Character.isDigit(c))
{
numbers++;
}
}
if (upperCase >= 2 && lowerCase >= 3 && numbers >= 1)
{
System.out.println("Valid password");
valid = true;
//valid set to true to break the while loop and end program. 
}
else 
System.out.println("The password did not have enough of the following:"); 
if (upperCase < 2)
System.out.println("uppercase letters");

if (lowerCase < 3)
System.out.println("lowercase letters");

if (numbers < 1)
System.out.println("digits");

}      
}
}
```

Comment: what is mindtap ?

Comment: Sounds like they're not sending a line to System.in. Are you sure they want you to use System.in to get the password?

Comment: try to add Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); line before the while loop

Comment: Mind tap is the online coding environment where the programs are tested. I tried to add the Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); line before the while loop, but the program wouldn't compile. At least I think I tried that but I can try again after work.

Comment: The point of putting the new Scanner(System.in) before the while loop, is that you only need to create a scanner once. So you also have to remove the Scanner keyboard = ... from inside the loop. I don't think it would change the results though. I suspect that you're returning the wrong error message, so they end their program. One way to get the error you're getting is to close the scanner.